# React Native - iOS WebView with Highcharts eventually drops series name; Android fine

Tags: react-native, highcharts, webview

I've run into a strange issue with iOS WebView that is rending a Highchart graph.  This issue does not exist on Android.  It only exists with series named a certain way (those that can be converted to numbers).

[iOS animated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyz12.gif) - Notice the series name disappears after a couple of seconds.

[Android (static image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvUuy.png) - The series name is never dropped.

You can find the [expo snack here](https://snack.expo.io/r1RmIfyiG) to play with it yourself.  If you run on android vs. iOS you'll notice the difference.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: Even though it works on Android?  When I switched to use wkwebview (3rd party react native component) this issues goes away.

Comment: Yes - it should work on iOS too.